# failed sale of chametz

Tags: selling-mechirat-chametz, history

Are there any recorded (recorded, perhaps, in responsa) instances of a failed sale of *chametz* (e.g., the gentile refused to buy the stuff and another couldn't be found, or the rabbi forgot to do it), in modern times (i.e., in a case that a whole community, and not just an individual tavernkeeper, was relying on the sale)? What was done about it?

Answer (score 3):

A certain *Beis Din* in Yerushalayim found out in about 1995 that they had been selling for quite a few years to someone who was really a Jew. I do not have any online sources nor do I wish to give away my sources for concerns of *Lashon Hara*.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vosizneias.com/82022/2011/04/22/jerusalem-charedim-find-gentile-chametz-buyer-has-taken-it

Comment: That was a successful sale, not a failed one.

Comment: @R'WAF: s/sale/transaction/

Answer (score 0):

It happened to my father-in-law - the community forgot to sell his Chametz one year. Since then he has always sold it himself directly to a non-Jew. But I don't think they forgot everyone's, they just misplaced his paper.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a whole community's stuff that was unsold, rather than an individual's.